# Connect Memu emulator to eclipse DDMS

Tags: java, android, android-studio, appium

Is there a way to connect other emulators like Memu to eclipse DDMS for appium testing? so far I've only found ways for Bluestakcs.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Memu version 2.8.3 with Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 on Windows 8. The connection port is 21503. Navigate in cmd to your SDK platform-tools directory and execute the following command >adb connect localhost:21503 then press enter, it should connect automatically. If it fails try installing sumsung USB driver and execute the command again, USB driver is not necessary but might be useful since mine shows samsung-gt_p5210-127.0.0.1:21503 under devices tab in Eclipse DDMS perspective. Memu is faster than Bluestacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Eclipse, then the Devices view, then - and only then - start (or restart) the Memu instance.